# When dividing a value by 60, getting error infdig scope error angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-infdig

I am writing a code to convert

`HH:MM` to `H.M` i.e `4:20` hrs == `4.33` hrs equivalent.

Here For that I want to convert the 20 minutes to `0.33` hrs by dividing it by `60`.

But everytime I get infdig scope error.

I have tried using

```
Number((minutes/60).toFixed(2))
```

-> no luck

```
Math.round((minutes/60 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
```

-> still no luck.

Can please anyone help me out here ?

Comment: give a `console.log(minutes)` and see the value in it

Comment: FYI 20/60 = 0.33

Comment: Yes its not a string. i logged values

Comment: [Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig#:~:text=Error%3A%20%24rootScope%3Ainfdig&text=This%20error%20occurs%20when%20the,the%20browser%20to%20become%20unresponsive.) I don't think it's because of the code you've shared. You're assigning something to the model that triggers a state change and requires an update in the next digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. An infdig scope error relates to a state change and subsequent $digest cycle in your component. See  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig